# Electric field of uniformly charged spherical cap?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

I was wondering what the electric field of a uniformly charged [spherical cap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap) is? Thereby I am referring to a spherical shell that was sliced into two pieces and we are only looking at one part of it. So in spherical coordinates it would mean that you would have a shell with radius $R$, it contains a full revolution of $2\pi$, but the polar angle does not go from $0$ to $\pi$ but rather from $0$ to some $\theta \in (0,\pi)$. And now I am looking for an equation that gives me the electric field for a given charge $Q$ on the shell.

It would be sufficient if somebody could give me the integral, that I have to evaluate!

Comment: Are you talking about a [spherical cap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap)?

Comment: Yes, but I did not know the word

Comment: You can derive it just like you derived it for a complete spherical shell(atleast I derived it that way) by taking infinitesimally thin parallel rings on the spherical cap, then using the formula for the field on the axis of a ring.

Comment: could you tell me your result in order to check, as I have never done this before?

Comment: Nah, I'm too lazy to derive because I know it'll be brain wrecking just to do the integrals, :-P. If you post your derivation here, and then I would check it.

Comment: you can write down the integral you got for me, I'll do it, but I was not able to follow your ideas, as I have never done this before

Comment: Check this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem, you can use the same analogy for charge instead of mass, and instead of integrating for the whole shell, you can put the limits according to you spherical cap.

Comment: Where is the charge $Q$ placed? Does it have any symmetries, or just a random point in the space?

Comment: Q is the uniform charge of this whole cap.